# Усилительные наречия

Tags: наречия

Как отличить усилительное наречие от не усилительного?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Усилительные наречия *очень, сильно, так* и другие выражают не сам признак действия, состояния, качества а лишь его степень: *очень громко, сильно уставший, так быстро*.

Обычно в грамматиках русского языка эта группа наречий специально не разбирается и вводится с одной только практической целью: частица "не" с ними пишется всегда раздельно.

> 7. Пишется раздельно не: а) с местоименными и усилительными наречиями,
>      например: .... не так, не вполне, не полностью, не совсем;

(Розенталь)
http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/38.htm

Примечание. Наречие "так" (эдак, и некоторые другие) является местоименным наречием, но в соответствующем контексте может одновременно быть и усилительным. С точки зрения орфографии здесь нет сложности, под указанное правило оно подпадает в любом случае.